# How can delete some rows or cols from cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

Assume that i have a cv::Mat(6000, 6000, CV_64F). how can is delete some rows or columns from that?

Comment: What exactly? A single row? From row A to row B? All even rows? ... ?

Comment: exactly delete rows that contain value 0 or value 200

Comment: probably you will have to create a new Mat and copy all the rows or cols except the ones you don't want anymore. you should create a list of row and col indices and some loops and skip the rows/cols during single element copying. If you can't create a second Mat because of Memory issues you could in-place copy to previous rows/cols when skipping and in the end create a sub-mat of the target size.

Comment: In in-place copy operations, memory not released and this is mistake. how to release memory in in-place copy?